# Unable to get all queues using the list_all_queues api

Tags: boto

I am running boto.sqs.get_all_queues(). This is only returning a maximum of 1000 queues.

How do I get back all the queues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SQS API does not provide a way to retrieve more than 1000 queues at a time and there is no pagination mechanism available.  It does provide a way to pass in a `prefix` and only queues whose name begins with the `prefix` are returned.  So, depending on how you have named your queues you may be able to use that prefix mechanism to implement your own pseudo-paging and eventually list all of your queues.  The `get_all_queues` method in boto supports the `prefix` parameter.